# Why is height in em units sometimes greater than appropriate count of text lines multiplied by their line height?

Tags: css

Consider the code:

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  font: 17px / 1.5 serif;
}

.floating {
  float: right;
  background: bisque;
  width: 10em;
  height: 9em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="floating"></span>
  Line 1<br>
  Line 2<br>
  Line 3<br>
  Line 4<br>
  Line 5<br>
  Line 6<br>
  Line 7 should not break
</p>
```

I struggle to understand what causes browsers (e.g. Chrome and Safari) to consider the floating block in this example to be taller than 6 lines of a very uniform text with line-height = 1.5, so that on font-size=17px the result looks like this:

[image: Line 7 is broken due to the clash with the floating element]

And, if let's say I pick font-size=20px, the result looks as expected:
[image: Line 7 is not broken, and the words "should not break" are exactly under the floating rectangle]

Is it a bug or something quite expected? If the latter is valid, where can I read about subtleties of computing the resulting line-height in pixels (probably, depending on font face properties)?

Comment: I can't replicate this issue... with any given font-size i get your desired result. What browser are you using?

Comment: @A.Meshu, my browser version is:

Google Chrome 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision 15234034d19b85dcd9a03b164ae89d04145d8368-refs/branch-heads/3578@{#897}

Comment: FF 68 actually work as expect... maybe it's a chrome bug.

Comment: @A.Meshu, also, I can reproduce it in Safari - Version 12.1.1 (14607.2.6.1.1)
So, it is not limited solely to Chrome. Maybe, that's the legacy of WebKit codebase, but not sure, that's why I asked.

Comment: Could be something to do with the way chrome renders those half pixels in the line height - if you remove 3px from the size of the floated box (for the 6 sets of 0.5px), it floats as you want it to.  I'm guessing the bug will appear for every odd font size (which is why it works for 20px)

Comment: @Pete, could you post a link to an example where you did that, please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/90gLrj8b/ - change to any odd font size and removing those 3px should make the box float properly

Comment: @Pete looks like you are right! So, the issue is primarily about handling the fractions of pixels.

Comment: Seems to be - looks like chrome rounds it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete), who came up with the idea of why that was happening.

As we found out, Webkit-based browsers handle pixel fractions in `line-height` a bit differently, compared to other browsers (e.g., Firefox).

The resulting `line-height` in the question was `17px * 1.5 = 25.5px`, and, as a result, each line of text occupied 25px, namely, `Math.floor` was implemented instead of any other theoretically possible option (`Math.ceil` or distributing 25px and 26px between odd and even lines, or whatever).

Hence, 6 lines occupied height equal to `25px * 6`, 150px. On the other hand, the height of the floating element was defined to be `25.5px * 6`, or simply 153px.

So, mathematically, we saw an occurrence of a common situation, when the sum of the `floor`-ed elements in a collection would be less or equal than the `floor`-ed sum of those elements, or:

[image: {\sum_i^n floor(L_i)} \leq floor({\sum_i^n L_i})], where L is a height of a line.

That's why an acceptable solution is to take into the account the Webkit's way of handling pixel fractions, the flooring. That would look uniformly (unless a bigger error accumulates) across the other browsers, even if they apply `ceil`-ing in this context.